# Fill JSP Table with ResultSet Data

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

I am trying to fill my JSP Table:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%" id="t01">
<tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<th>Wednesday</th>
<th>Thursday</th>
<th>Friday</th>
<th>Saturday</th>
<th>Sunday</th>
</tr>
<%
int id = 1;
int y = 7;

for(int i = 0; i < 15;i++){
     if (i!=0){ %>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><%=y%>:00</td><%
        y=y+1;
     }
     else{%>
          <tr>
          <td><%=y%>:00</td>
          <%
          y=y+1;
          }
   for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++ ){ %>
        <td id=<%=id%> onclick="go(this)"> </td>
        <%
         id = id+1;
    }

  }
  %>
```

With Data from my ResultSet, which i retrieve with Java, like this:

```
//Establishing Connection to DB
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","123456");
Statement st= con.createStatement();
//Getting Data for td's
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Appointments");
```

What's the best way, to insert my Appointments into this table?

SQL Table - Appointments has got following columns:
Name, Id, User

Where id refers to the Time Cell, in which it happens.

I thought of maybe getting the Ids of every Appointment in the Database and insert it into the creation of the JSP Table, but i really don't know how.

Comment: so what is the question What's the best way, to insert my Appointments into this table? or or you having trouble in Filling JSP Table with ResultSet Data

Comment: @NarendraJaggi Well both kinda. I've tried many ways, non of them worked, so i was wondering if someone had an easy solution for this problem.

Comment: id in ur table refers time cell what is the range for that??

Comment: Don't know what you mean..?